# Insert into string after nth occurrence of token

Tags: c#, html, string

I have the following HTML in a string variable `myHtml`.The `myHTML` variable is filled with HTML from some function which return the HTML as follows

```
string myHtml="<table> <tr id='12345'><td>Hello1</td></tr> <tr id='12346'><td>Hello2</td></tr> </table>";
```

In this example, there are two rows in my returned data, and I need to add another row between the above rows with `id=1234678`.  So then `myHtml` might look like

```
myHtml="<table> <tr id='12345'><td>Hello1</td></tr> <tr id='1234678'><td>Hello New</td></tr>  <tr id='12346'><td>Hello2</td></tr> </table>";
```

I want to do it by appending the HTML with the help of string operations such as indexOf, etc, but I can not figure out how to do this.

Comment: I wanted to do something with indexOf by getting the tr tag with the orderid but in vain

Comment: Use substring. Split string to pieces, add something inside then join. Am I right?

Comment: @asawyer, eh on number 2.  Jeff Atwood considers 70% "quite good", so presumably 67% is fairly good - http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/

Comment: Why not use XML methods? Why do you want to use string operations like indexOf?

Comment: I would say that what are your asking is a horrible way to try and manipulate html, and I would avoid what you are asking like the plague...nothing good can come of it!

Comment: @dsolimano Gotcha, I'll keep that in mind then. Sorry Abbas! Hmm Where'd my other comment go? Weird.

Comment: I am doing it in C# code...and I ahve a string ...this is a restriction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there always only 2 rows? If so, this will work:

```
string newRow = " <tr id='1234678'><td>Hello New</td></tr> ";
int i = myHtml.IndexOf("</tr>") + 5;            
string newHtml = myHtml.Insert(i, newRow);
```

If there could by any number of rows, we'll need to write a method to find the specific index to insert at.

e.g:

```
    int IndexOfNth(string source, string token, int nTh)
    {
        int index = source.IndexOf(token);

        if (index != -1)
        {
            int i = 1;
            while (i++ < nTh)
                index = source.IndexOf(token, index + 1);
        }

        return index;
    }
```

Then you would use:

```
int i = IndexOfNth(myHtml, "</tr>", 1) + 5; // find first "</tr>" and insert after

// Or you could use
int i = IndexOfNth(myHtml, "<tr ", 2); // find second "<tr " and insert before
```

Comment: I want to insert before a row with a specific id...will this work for specific id...and therecan be infinite rows

Comment: To insert before a specific id, you would use e.g. `IndexOfNth(myHtml, "<tr id='12346'>", 1)` but if the id is unique then you could just use `myHtml.IndexOf("<tr id='12346'>")` because it will always be the first occurance.

Comment: However you really have to be careful with this because if the HTML isn't perfectly formatted, it could break. (That's why you should use a proper HTML manipulation library).

Answer (score 5):

Don't use strings for this but a library for this. For example the [HTML agility pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex)

Comment: Why not? HTML agility pack is the best way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Because i am not allowed to se anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    myHtml = "<table> <tr id='12345'><td>Hello1</td></tr> <tr id='12346'><td>Hello2</td></tr> </table>";
    int index1 = myHtml.IndexOf("<tr", 0);
    int index2 = myHtml.IndexOf("<tr", index1 + 3); // 3 for amount of characters in '<tr'
    myHtml = myHtml.Insert(index2, "<tr id='1234678'><td>Hello</td></tr>");
```

You could also build an array via a loop so you can insert the row wherever you'd like if there are more than two existing rows.

Comment: What is the 3 for ...can you please explain a bit more??

Comment: The index of will return the value where the first opening bracket "<" arises.  We want to take in consideration the fact that we're doing an IndexOf for 3 characters ("<tr").

Answer (score 1):

Try using Linq to XML. Create a XDocument based on your string. Then search for your tr node and insert your new tr node.

```
var newTR = new XElement("tr", new XAttribute("id", "1234678"), new XElement("td", "Hello3"));
TextReader tr = new StringReader(myHtml);
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(tr);
doc.Decendants().Skip(1).AddAfterSelf(newTR);
var newStr = doc.ToString();
```